# How to fit the size of the three.js renderer to a webpage element?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I need to fit the size of the renderer to the size of an element on the webpage. Doing `renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)` sets the size of the renderer to fit the whole window.

```js
init() {
      let map = document.getElementById('map');
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        //window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        1341/958, //hardcoded for now, but needs to be automatic
        0.1,
        1000,
      );
      this.camera.position.z = 3;
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      //this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); // it should not be a whole window
      this.renderer.setSize(1341,958); //hardcoded for now, but needs to be automatic
      map.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);}
```

EXPECTED: if you uncomment the comments the whole renderer takes the size of the whole window.

ACTUAL: I had to hardcode the dimensions myself, but it is just a hotfix :(

Comment: `map.style.height` and `map.style.width` should return the sizes you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the dimensions of the element that contains your renderer (`<canvas>`) with `getBoundingClientRect`. Below is a little demo, showing the scaling of a `<canvas>` to the dimensions of a surrounding `<div>`:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var canvas = document.querySelector('#stage');

function scaleToFit (container, node) {
  var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  node.width = rect.width;
  node.height = rect.height;
}

setTimeout(function () { scaleToFit(container, canvas); }, 1000);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#stage {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="stage" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</div>
```

For your usecase, you can change your code like this:

```js
init() {
      let map = document.getElementById('map');
      let mapDimensions = map.getBoundingClientRect();

      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        mapDimensions.width/mapDimensions.height,
        0.1,
        1000,
      );
      this.camera.position.z = 3;
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      this.renderer.setSize(mapDimensions.width, mapDimensions.height);
      map.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use it and tell you if it works :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you! The additional problem in my code was, that I am working with Vuetify.js as well, so it causing additional issues.

Comment: @RaulS Glad it helped :)